# Dynamic shape selection in plotly

Tags: plotly, r-plotly

To highlight regions in a timeseries I use `layout > shapes` objects, as described here: [How to add colored background bars in plotly.js chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55035114/how-to-add-colored-background-bars-in-plotly-js-chart)

Now each of these background shapes has a "type", and I would like the user to be able to show/hide specific types, just like with traces (e.g. show only V4 and V5, hide V3, as in the example below).

[image]

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

This can in principle achieved by using traces insetad of shapes to specify the background regions. This way the background regions show up in the legend. Using some random example data try this:

```
library(plotly)
set.seed(42)
d <- data.frame(
  x=as.Date(c('2015-02-01', '2015-02-02', '2015-02-03', '2015-02-04', '2015-02-05',
     '2015-02-06', '2015-02-07', '2015-02-08', '2015-02-09', '2015-02-10',
     '2015-02-11', '2015-02-12', '2015-02-13', '2015-02-14', '2015-02-15',
     '2015-02-16', '2015-02-17', '2015-02-18', '2015-02-19', '2015-02-20',
     '2015-02-21', '2015-02-22', '2015-02-23', '2015-02-24', '2015-02-25',
     '2015-02-26', '2015-02-27', '2015-02-28')),
  y=runif(28, 350, 550)
)
d

range_y <- list(min = floor(min(d$y) / 100) * 100, max = ceiling(max(d$y) / 100) * 100)

shape1 <- data.frame(x = as.Date(c('2015-02-01', '2015-02-08')), y = c(range_y$max, range_y$max))
shape2 <- data.frame(x = as.Date(c('2015-02-23', '2015-02-27')), y = c(range_y$max, range_y$max))

plot_ly(x=~x, y=~y) %>% 
  add_trace(data = d, mode = "lines+markers", type = "scatter") %>% 
  add_trace(data = shape1, mode = "none", fill = "tozeroy", name = "type1") %>% 
  add_trace(data = shape2, mode = "none", fill = "tozeroy", name = "type2") %>% 
  layout(yaxis = list(range = c(range_y$min, range_y$max)))
```

[image]

Comment: This is indeed a viable solution. +1. Note though that a limit on the y-axis has to be specified in this case. The reason why I initially opted to use the `layout > shape` is because then the bars can range vertically from `-Inf` up to `Inf`.

Comment: Yep. That's a drawback of using the trace.